# BASH - How to use sed to pull out the URLS from a website

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have this

```
exec 5<>/dev/tcp/twitter.ca/80
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.0\n" >&5
cat <&5
```

I looked a similar script

```
curl http://cookpad.com 2>&1 | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' | cut -d'"' -f2
```

but I need to use the sed command only.

the output i get is this

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command


#!/bin/bash

exec 5<>/dev/tcp/twitter.ca/80
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.0\n" >&5
cat <&5 | sed -r -e 'href="([^"#]+)"'
```

Is what I currently have and I guess what im trying to do is how to use sed to strip it of all extras and keep it with just the htmls?

my output should be look something like this:

```
href="UnixFortune.apk"
href="UnixFortune-1.0.tgz"
href="BeagleCar.apk"
href="BeagleCar.zip"
```

Comment: what exactly did you try with sed already?

Answer (score 0):

[`sed`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) is a scripting language.  Your command looks like you are trying to use the `h` command (copy pattern to hold space) with options starting with `ref=`... but the `h` command doesn't take any options.

Anyway, the command you want is the `s` command, which performs substitutions.  Namely, you want to substitute everything before and after the matching group with nothing (and thus print only the captured group).

```
sed -r -e 's/.*href="([^"#]+)".*/\1/'
```

However, this still doesn't do the right thing if there are multiple matches on a line (or lines without a match, although that is easy to fix with `sed -n 's/.../p'`).  You can certainly solve that in `sed`, but I would suggest you go with `grep -o` instead, unless you specifically want to learn, write, and maintain `sed` script.  (Or, alternatively, rewrite into an Awk or Perl script.  Perl in particular has a lot more leverage for tasks like this.)

And of course, for this particular task, the proper tool is an HTML parser.  There is no way to properly pick apart HTML using just regular expressions.  See e.g. [How to extract links from a webpage using lxml, XPath and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084670/how-to-extract-links-from-a-webpage-using-lxml-xpath-and-python)